# Export command in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I very much new to shell script. I was analyzing a script where i found a line as below

**ABC="$GENABC +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 -8"  ; export ABC**

I don't understand what does +1 +2 etc stands for. Kindly explain me.

Comment: I  don't think it does anything. :)
If you run a "export |grep ABC" it will give the same input as output

Answer (score 2):

As rjdkolb indicates the `+` characters there are just that, literal `+` characters in the value of the `ABC` variable.

You could have seen that easily enough yourself by trying it.

As I've done, for example, at http://ideone.com/H6vMeg

```
$ GENABC="original value"
$ ABC="$GENABC +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 -8" ; export ABC
$ declare -p ABC
declare -x ABC="original value +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 -8"
```